# how to send data from array to pointer variable and back from pointer variable to array?

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, pointers, client-server

```
#include "MAIN.h"
#include "xcpip_callbacks.h"
typedef unsigned _int16 uint16;
typedef unsigned _int8 uint8;

uint16 port = 18017;
void XcpApp_IpTransmit( uint16 port, Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes, uint16 numBytes )

{
        WSADATA wsa;
        SOCKET s;
        uint8 bytes_recieved;
        uint8 send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];

        struct sockaddr_in server;  // creating a socket address structure: structure contains ip address and port number

        printf("Initializing Winsock\n");
        if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa)!=0)
        {
            printf("Failed Error Code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Initialised\n");



        //int sock, bytes_recieved;  
        //char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];
        //struct hostent *host;
        //struct sockaddr_in server_addr;  

        //host = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

        /*if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("Socket");
            exit(1);
        }*/


        //CREATING a SOCKET

        if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        {
            printf("Could not Create Socket\n");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("Socket Created\n");

        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;     
        server.sin_port = htons("port");   

        //Connect to a remote server
        if(connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server))<0)
        {
        puts("Connect Error\n");
        return 1;
        }

        puts("Connected\n");


        //SENDING a data


        /* bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 

        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                    sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) 
        {
            perror("Connect");
            exit(1);
        }*/

        while(1)
        {
        /*
            s- socket
            recv_data - receive data buffer and size of it (1024)
        */
          bytes_recieved=recv(s,recv_data,1024,0);
          recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';

          if(strcmp(recv_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(recv_data , "Q") == 0)
          {
           close(s);
           break;
          }

          else
           printf("\nRecieved data = %s " , recv_data);

          /*
          port For TCP: the port which listened for the connection which
                        was used to transmit the data. Note that this may not be
                        the same as the port which actually transmitted the data.
          For UDP:      the port which transmitted the data.
                        numTxBytes The number of bytes which were transmitted during the
                        latest call to XcpApp_IpTransmit(). For TCP, this may
                        be less than the total number of bytes which were supplied
                        to XcpApp_IpTransmit().*/


          XcpIp_TxCallback(uint16 port, uint16 numTxBytes );

           printf("\nSEND (q or Q to quit) : ");
           gets(send_data);

          if (strcmp(send_data , "q") != 0 && strcmp(send_data , "Q") != 0)
           send(s,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0); 

          else
          {
           send(s,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0); 

           /*
         chunkLen :  The number of bytes at pChunkData.
         pChunkData : The payload of the received IP frame. The caller does not
                      need to interpret the payload: the entire payload should be
                      passed to XcpIp_RxCallback().
                      The caller can discard this data after the function returns.
        port For TCP:  the port which listened for the connection which
                       received the data. Note that this may not be the same as
                       the port which actually received the data.
        For UDP:       the port which received the data. */

          XcpIp_RxCallback(uint16 chunkLen, uint8* pChunkData, uint16 port);

           closesocket(s);
           WSACleanup();
           break;
          }

        }   

}
```

I have created a TCP Layer for sending and receiving the data on the specific port and calling some specific XCP protocol to perform some activity. I have created a socket and specified the port number and ip address to send and receive data. I am receiving some data on the recv_data[1024]; I can send data from the send_data[1024];

I need some help for :
Before writing or sending that data: I should send the data from send_data[1024] to Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes (pointer points to memory in an address space). Later I have to write data from Xcp_StatePtr8 pBytes to recv_data[1024];

Could anyone please suggest me some ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use memcpy to write the data from an array to a pointer and vice versa like this example I created below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

#define MAX_SIZE 20

int main()
{
    int anTest[MAX_SIZE] = {200, 200, 200, 200};
    int anTest2[MAX_SIZE];
    int* pnTest = new int[MAX_SIZE];

    // Initializing array and pointer to 0
    memset(anTest2, 0, sizeof(anTest2));
    memset(pnTest, 0, sizeof(pnTest));

    //Outputting anTest values and exiting loop when
    //an element contains 0, just because.
    puts("anTest values: ");
    for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex < MAX_SIZE; nIndex++)
    {
        if (0 == anTest[nIndex])
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("%d: %d\n", nIndex, anTest[nIndex]);
    }

    //Copying array to pointer
    memcpy(pnTest, anTest, MAX_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    //Copying pointer to array
    memcpy(anTest2, pnTest, MAX_SIZE * sizeof(int));

    //Outputting anTest2 values and exiting loop when
    //an element contains 0, just because.
    puts("\nanTest2 values: ");
    for(int nIndex = 0; nIndex < MAX_SIZE; nIndex++)
    {
        if (0 == anTest2[nIndex])
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("%d: %d\n", nIndex, anTest2[nIndex]);
    }

    //Deleting pointer since it's no longer needed.
    delete pnTest;
    pnTest = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

[EDIT] I forgot to add code to prove that it works (I always check my code by walking through the code instead of outputting the values lol). I edited my code to include printing the output values.

Comment: Your welcome :), be sure to accept my answer and upvote it when you believe this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Don't worry about it then, I guess it is because you do not have high enough reputation, but I bet you are able to accept my answer though :).

Comment: Yes, Your answer was useful for me.

Comment: Lol I meant vote on your answer, there should be a button that says something like "mark answer as accepted" or something like that.